# C# Linq to SQL datagridview showing object in row

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

In my datacontext, I have an employee table/class with 2 columns (id and description). When I show the values on the datagridview, it shows as the object.column (see image)

How do I set it to show the description instead of the ID?

```
private void FormEmployees_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    employeeBindingSource.DataSource = dataContext.Employees.ToList();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey mate - if TypesEmployee is an enum see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/abhinaba/2005/10/20/c-enum-and-overriding-tostring-on-it/. If it is a different type override ToString on the type.

Comment: To paraphrase @Andrew: What type is the data in that column? What you are likely seeing is the DGV trying to convert your data to a string for display. If i had to guess, I'd guess that your data is a `ClubsDeGolf.TypesE{something}`. The default implementation of ToString just outputs the type name. If you override ToString in your type, your override will be used to generate the string.